# android: Variable in runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, final, webviewrunonuithread

Hi i m using Android Studio, and I am using Deprecated function in a runOnUiThread
It forces me to use a a Final Variable inside the runOnUiThread
this is ok for the new function but for the Deprecated function i get an error

```
Error:(133, 16) error: incompatible types
required: Thread
found:    void
```

anyone can help to fix this.

```
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                String sURL = "http://pollsdb.com/schlogger/223.png";

                URL url = null;
                url = new URL(sURL);
                assert url != null;

                Bitmap bmp = null;
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 200, 200, false);
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);

                final BitmapDrawable fbmpdw = bitmapDrawable;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            ib1.setBackground(fbmpdw);
                        } else {
                            ib1.setBackgroundDrawable(fbmpdw); // <---- this the problem
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is not the `setBackgroudDrawable` method, but `Thread.start()`, which returns nothing (`void`), while you are trying to assign its return value to the `thread` local variable

You can both change  `Thread thread = new Thread() { ... }` and then call `thread.start()` or simply  `new Thread() { ... }.start();` without assignment

Comment: thanks that was a quick answer, thanks a lot I used thread.start(); instead seems ok.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use the `thread` variable anywhere else? I don't think you need to.
If so, simply change in your first line

```
 Thread thread = new Thread() {
```

To

```
new Thread() {
```

Your .start() will return void, and you cannot do `Thread thread=//some thing void` as it is expecting some Thread type.